# How to get key value pairs of the objects from complex JSON using jq and map? (Active Campaign)

Tags: json, jq, activecampaign

I have following JSON. I want to get key-value pair objects based on their role. In this example there are 3 roles(Presenter, Approver, Customer) but there can be more as it is dynamic.

JSON

```json
{
   "Presenter Name": "Roney",
   "Presenter Email": "roney@domain.com",
   "Approver Name": "Tim",
   "Approver Email": "tim@domain.com",
   "Customer Name": "Alex",
   "Customer Email": "alex@domain.com",   
   "Invoice": "001",
   "Date": "2022-02-14"   
}
```

Expected output using jq, map,

```json
{
    "Presenter": {
      "email_address": "roney@domain.com",
      "name": "Roney",
      "role": "Presenter"
    },
    "Approver": {
      "email_address": "tim@domain.com",
      "name": "Tim",
      "role": "Approver"
    },
    "Customer": {
      "email_address": "alex@domain.com",
      "name": "Alex",
      "role": "Customer"
    }
}
```

I have tried till following but didn't get what to do next. Please advice.

`to_entries |map( { (.key): { name: .value, email_address:.value, role: .key} } ) | add`

Comment: `add` would be useful if you had `[ { "Presenter": { ... } }, { "Approver": { ... } }, ... ]`. It would also be useful for a given role if you had `[ { "email_address": ... },  { "name": ... }, { "role": ... } ]`. But' it's more convenient to place it in the final format directly than in these formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another, shorter approach that doesn't use `group_by`. Instead, this directly iterates over the initial object using `reduce` and imediately sets all the fields accordingly if the key followed the space-separated role-key pattern.

```sh
reduce (to_entries[] | .key /= " ") as {key: [$role, $key], $value} ({};
  if $key then
    .[$role] += {({Email: "email_address", Name: "name"}[$key]): $value, $role}
  else . end
)
```

```json
{
  "Presenter": {
    "name": "Roney",
    "role": "Presenter",
    "email_address": "roney@domain.com"
  },
  "Approver": {
    "name": "Tim",
    "role": "Approver",
    "email_address": "tim@domain.com"
  },
  "Customer": {
    "name": "Alex",
    "role": "Customer",
    "email_address": "alex@domain.com"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nX4YANVgKi)

Comment: What changes I should do to get list of objects `[ { "Presenter": { ... } }, { "Approver": { ... } }, { "Customer": { ... } } ]` rather current one `{ { "Presenter": { ... } }, { "Approver": { ... } }, { "Customer": { ... } } }`

Comment: @NJBhanushali Add `| to_entries | map({(.key): .value})` to this solution. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cHjYa5zPeK)

Answer (score 3):

This `split`s the keys at the space character while discarding any items that don't have one in it. Then it assigns the three fields to their values accordingly, using `reduce` to combine the grouping.

```
to_entries
| map(.key |= split(" ") | select(.key[1]))
| reduce group_by(.key[0])[] as $g ({};
    .[$g[0].key[0]] = (
      INDEX($g[]; .key[1]) | {
        email_address: .Email.value,
        name: .Name.value,
        role: .Name.key[0]
      }
    )
  )
```

```json
{
  "Approver": {
    "email_address": "tim@domain.com",
    "name": "Tim",
    "role": "Approver"
  },
  "Customer": {
    "email_address": "alex@domain.com",
    "name": "Alex",
    "role": "Customer"
  },
  "Presenter": {
    "email_address": "roney@domain.com",
    "name": "Roney",
    "role": "Presenter"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DgOQ-xgPv_)

Comment: I have tried this. I am getting this error `jq: error: INDEX/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:`. I make 2 change. 1- Removed `role: .Name.key[0]`, 2- Use Email instead of Name like this `role: .Email.key[0]`. Can you please help me? I don't want name anymore.

Comment: @NJBhanushali `INDEX/2` is part of the [SQL-StyleOperators](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#SQL-StyleOperators) introduced in jq v1.6. It looks like you are running an older version.

Comment: I am using this code in ActiveCampaign. It uses older version and I can't upgrade it. Can you please let me to work around this. I am doing code in ActiveCampaign App Studio: https://developers.activecampaign.com/docs/configuration-walkthrough-1

Comment: I want to get result like this https://jqplay.org/s/yMC7enLLaL

Comment: @NJBhanushali It'd be much simpler for us (and more comprehensible for others reading this) if you opened a new question with full details (as you did originally in this one: what is the source, what is the desired output, etc.)

Comment: I have post new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71211622/how-to-get-object-list-from-key-value-pairs-complex-json-using-jq-and-map-acti

Answer (score 1):

```
{ "Name": "name",  "Email": "email_address" } as $key_map |
to_entries |
map (
   ( .key | split(" ") | select( length == 2 ) ) as [ $role, $raw_key ] |
   [ $role, "role",             $role  ],
   [ $role, $key_map[$raw_key], .value ]
) |
reduce .[] as [ $role, $key, $val ] ( {}; .[ $role ][ $key ] = $val )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zH98zj6rA0) on jqplay

---

In the above, we start by making the data uniform. Specifically, we start by producing the following:

```
[
   [ "Presenter", "role",          "Presenter"        ],
   [ "Presenter", "name",          "Roney"            ],
   [ "Presenter", "role",          "Presenter"        ],
   [ "Presenter", "email_address", "roney@domain.com" ],
   [ "Approver",  "role",          "Approver"         ],
   [ "Approver",  "name",          "Tim"              ],
   [ "Approver",  "role",          "Approver"         ],
   [ "Approver",  "email_address", "tim@domain.com"   ],
   [ "Customer",  "role",          "Customer"         ],
   [ "Customer",  "name",          "Alex"             ],
   [ "Customer",  "role",          "Customer"         ],
   [ "Customer",  "email_address", "alex@domain.com"  ]
]
```

There's redundant information, but that doesn't matter.

Then, the final simple `reduce` builds the desired structure.

---

```
.key | split(" ") | select( length == 2 )
```

can be replaced with the safer

```
.key | match("^(.*) (Name|Email)$") | .captures | map( .string )
```

Comment: @pmf's earlier is perfectly fine, but I believe this one is easier to understand.