# How to get object list from key value pairs complex JSON using jq and map? (Active Campaign)

Tags: json, jq, activecampaign

I have following JSON. I want to get key-value pair objects based on their CC role. In this example there are 3 roles(Presenter, Approver, Customer). Presenter is of type `TO`. Other 2 are of type `CC`. I want to get of type `CC`. There can be more as it is dynamic.

JSON

```
{
   "Presenter_TO_Email": "roney@domain.com",
   "Approver_CC_Email": "tim@domain.com",
   "Customer_CC_Email": "alex@domain.com",   
   "Invoice": "001",
   "Date": "2022-02-14"   
}
```

Output

```
{
    "Approver": {
      "email_address": "tim@domain.com",
      "role": "Approver"
    },
    "Customer": {
      "email_address": "alex@domain.com",
      "role": "Customer"
    }
}
```

I can do using INDEX using [this](https://jqplay.org/s/epn55D_OGj) example but as I am using older version of `jq`, it throws error `jq: error: INDEX/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with_entries` to make changes based on keys and values:

```sh
jq '
  with_entries(
    (.key / "_CC_") as $key | select($key[1])
    | {key: $key[0], value: {email_address: .value, role: $key[0]}}
  )
'
```

```json
{
  "Approver": {
    "email_address": "tim@domain.com",
    "role": "Approver"
  },
  "Customer": {
    "email_address": "alex@domain.com",
    "role": "Customer"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-uPNpDR4fX)

Answer (score 1):

In versions of jq which include `INDEX/2`, it is defined as a simple jq function, so if your jq does not include it, you can simply include its definition yourself:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);
```